# SharePoint Online Audience Targeting for Regional Groups

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am in the process of creating a training and events site in SharePoint for a non-profit organization that will have news posts targeted to 4 different geographical regions. These posts will be created and edited by multiple authors. If I wanted to make it easy for the news post editors to go to one page location with dropdown menus to add and edit posts for 4 different target audiences, what would be the wisest/most efficient method of accomplishing this goal?

Thank you for any advice if you have worked with the latest version of SharePoint!

Best,
Matthew Shuster

Comment: stackoverflow is a site for programming questions, your question does not seem to be related to programming. You can try "super user" forum from the stackoverflow family, or Microsoft community user forums.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my confusion! I'm new to the tech forum world..

Comment: There's actually a SharePoint Stack Exchange site (cc @Nikolay) at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com - however, you should read their tour (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) to make sure your question is a good fit there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to target specific news post pages to specific audiences in a page library. Here're steps:

1.Go to the pages library settings -> select Audience targeting settings -> enable it,

2.From the library, select a page, select the ellipses then select Details.

3.In the details pane, select a value for the Audience property.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.